# PHP How to get the intersection of two or more arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the intersection of two or more arrays with this kind of structure:

First array:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        ['room_id'] => 21
        ['room_name'] => 'GB 101'
        ['capacity'] => 40
    )
    [1] => array(
        ['room_id'] => 22
        ['room_name'] => 'H 114'
        ['capacity'] => 20
    )
    [2] => array(
        ['room_id'] => 23
        ['room_name'] => 'GB 203'
        ['capacity'] => 20
    )
    [3] => array(
        ['room_id'] => 25
        ['room_name'] => 'H 100'
        ['capacity'] => 30
    )
    [4] => array(
        ['room_id'] => 26
        ['room_name'] => 'GB 206'
        ['capacity'] => 40
    )
)
```

Second Array:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        ['room_id'] => 21
        ['room_name'] => 'GB 101'
        ['capacity'] => 40
    )
    [1] => array(
        ['room_id'] => 23
        ['room_name'] => 'GB 203'
        ['capacity'] => 20
    )
    [2] => array(
        ['room_id'] => 26
        ['room_name'] => 'GB 206'
        ['capacity'] => 40
    )
)
```

Resulting array:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        ['room_id'] => 21
        ['room_name'] => 'GB 101'
        ['capacity'] => 40
    )
    [1] => array(
        ['room_id'] => 23
        ['room_name'] => 'GB 203'
        ['capacity'] => 20
    )
    [2] => array(
        ['room_id'] => 26
        ['room_name'] => 'GB 206'
        ['capacity'] => 40
    )
)
```

I tried using array_intersect_assoc to get the intersection using the following code:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect_assoc', $arrays);
```

It does the trick but it gives the following warning which is expected according [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61118&edit=1):

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion

I am making an Ajax based system so the error messes it up. Is there any way to get the intersection of the arrays?

Comment: Difference between your second and your result array is ?

Comment: That is because all elements of the second array is in the first one.
Here is an analogy of a different scenario:
array 1 = (1,2,3)
array 2 = (2,4,6)
array 3 = (1,2,7)
resulting array = (2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try serializing them:

```
$result = array_map('unserialize',
              array_intersect(
                  array_map('serialize', $first), array_map('serialize', $second)));
```

- `array_map()` runs each sub-array of the main arrays through `serialize()` which converts each sub-array into a string representation of that sub-array

  - the main arrays now have values that are not arrays but string representations of the sub-arrays
- `array_intersect()` now has a one-dimensional array for each of the arrays to compare
- after the intersection is returned `array_map()` runs the array result (intersection) through `unserialize()` to turn the string representations back into sub-arrays

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I was able to extend it to any number of arrays by using
$result = array_map('unserialize', call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $arrays));
and using 
array_map('serialize', $array)
to each array before adding it to $arrays

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thanks!

Would be nice if there was a brief explanation tho.

Comment: @JavanoCollins  Edited... thanks!  This was an earlier answer or I was in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_uintersect()` to use a custom comparison function, for example compare by `room_id`.

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    "0" => array(
        "room_id" => 21,
        "room_name" => 'GB 101',
        "capacity" => 40
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "room_id" => 22,
        "room_name" => 'H 114',
        "capacity" => 20
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "room_id" => 23,
        "room_name" => 'GB 203',
        "capacity" => 20
    ),
    "3" => array(
        "room_id" => 25,
        "room_name" => 'H 100',
        "capacity" => 30
    ),
    "4" => array(
        "room_id" => 26,
        "room_name" => 'GB 206',
        "capacity" => 40
    )
);

$array2 = array(
    "0" => array(
        "room_id" => 21,
        "room_name" => 'GB 101',
        "capacity" => 40
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "room_id" => 23,
        "room_name" => 'GB 203',
        "capacity" => 20
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "room_id" => 26,
        "room_name" => 'GB 206',
        "capacity" => 40
    )
);

$intersect = array_uintersect($array1, $array2, 'compareDeepValue');

function compareDeepValue($val1, $val2)
{
   return strcmp($val1['room_id'], $val2['room_id']);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($intersect);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [room_id] => 21
            [room_name] => GB 101
            [capacity] => 40
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [room_id] => 23
            [room_name] => GB 203
            [capacity] => 20
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [room_id] => 26
            [room_name] => GB 206
            [capacity] => 40
        )    
)
```

Comment: array_intersect_assoc() gives an 'Array to string conversion' notice which messes up my Ajax call.

Comment: You can also use `array_uintersect()` and comepare by `room_id`

Answer (score 0):

To compare two multidimensional arrays , a simple solution would be

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $sub_array1)
{
   foreach($array2 as $sub_array2)
   {
       if($sub_array1 === $sub_array2)
       {
            $new_array[] = $sub_array2;
       }
   }
}

print_r($new_array);
```